# Raspberry Pi communication over USB

Tags: usb, remote, lxterminal

Is it possible to communicate with the Raspberry Pi over USB?

Basically is it possible to write a device driver on my x86 PC running Linux, and also tweak the OS running on the RPi so that a communication channel is established? This should enable say a small terminal to be run remotely on the Rpi from the PC over USB. I am aware that the same can of course be done over Ethernet, but I'm curious as to why a similar application over USB does not exist.

Comment: How about serial communication? I don't know of any methods to connect two computers directly using only the USB standard

Comment: "I'm curious as to why a similar application over USB does not exist." You'll probably find this is because other methods are much easier, eg Ethernet or serial (RS-232/422 through GPIO).

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use the `usbnet` driver ([usbnet homepage](http://www.linux-usb.org/usbnet/)) which allow you to map USB port as they were Ethernet port. Then you can route traffic through your USB port and therefore `ssh` your RPi by the mean of a regular USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an FTDI cable like [this one from Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/954).